# Is there a way to change the order that 3 HTML elements show up (ie, there weight in relation to each other)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 "p" elements and I was wondering if there was a way that I could change the order that the page loads them with JS or CSS. Below is an attached copy of what I have tried. As you can see, when you click on the first box labeled "about 1" when it opens it and shows the small boxes for the other boxes below so you can click on them. This is what I want to happen to all of them. So basically I want the order of how the boxes are loaded by the HTML to change when I click on a box. ie, when I click on box 2, then the HTML element **News / Updates / Anouncements** will be moved above **About 1** and **About 2** so that the result when I click on it will be the box opens, and you can see both links at the bottom.

I hope someone can help because I am utterly stuck.

Thanks!

(So basically what happens when you click **About 1** for all of the boxes!)

```css
body {
  background-color: #000080;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -530px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 585px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.box1:focus {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #dfff00;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -530px;
  left: 225px;
  height: 585px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.box2:focus {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 500px;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -530px;
  left: 400px;
  height: 585px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.box3:focus {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #dfff00;
}

.boxTitle {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0" class="box1">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>About 1</u></b></span>
</p>

<p tabindex="0" class="box3">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>About 2</u></b></span>
</p>



<p tabindex="0" class="box2">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>News / Updates / Anouncements</u></b></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `z-index`.

Set a `z-index` on the `body` tag and then add a default `z-index` to each box. I added a generic `box` class to each box, to set the base style. Then on `focus`, you set the `z-index` to lower than the base `z-index`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000080;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box {
  z-index: 3;
  /* common to all boxes */
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 585px;
  bottom: -530px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.box:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  /* These are common to all boxes */
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 500px;
}

.box1 {
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.box1:focus {
  background-color: #dfff00;
}

.box2 {
  left: 225px;
  width: 125px;
}

.box3 {
  left: 400px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box3:focus {
  background-color: #dfff00;
}

.boxTitle {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0" class="box1 box">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>About 1</u></b></span>
</p>

<p tabindex="0" class="box3 box">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>About 2</u></b></span>
</p>

<p tabindex="0" class="box2 box">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>News / Updates / Anouncements</u></b></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of making sure that the clicked box is layered behind the other two.

Also, there's no need to repeat CSS classes that are only different by one property. Instead, set up one class that has all the common properties and apply that class to each "box". Only set up separate classes for properties that are different for each item.

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll("p");

// Loop over each of the paragraph boxes
boxes.forEach(function(box){
  // Add a click event handler
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Loop over all the boxes again
    boxes.forEach(function(b){
      // give all the boxes a high z-index
      // so that they are all layered on top of everything else
      b.style.zIndex = 100;
    });
    // Give the clicked box a low z-index so that it
    // goes behind the other boxes
    this.style.zIndex = -100;
  }); 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000080;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* All of the following applies to each box so
   just set up a class that each will use instead
   of making 3 classes that only differ by one thing */
.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -530px;
  height: 585px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Same here */
.box:focus {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #dfff00;
}

/* Then, set up separate classes for what is different
   for each one. */
.box1 { left:50px;   }
.box2 { left: 225px; }
.box3 { left: 400px; }

.boxTitle {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0" class="box box1">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>About 1</u></b></span>
</p>

<p tabindex="0" class="box box3">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>About 2</u></b></span>
</p>

<p tabindex="0" class="box box2">
  <span class="boxTitle"><b><u>News / Updates / Anouncements</u></b></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any js for this. In each `:focus` add `z-index: -1;`. That should push the element behind the other when focused.